# VanillaTilt.js and querySelectorAll to destroy tilt in divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to destroy VanillaTilt on few divs when screen size is smaller than 800px. Of course my function works with one div but not with few ones. I thought that i can use a  querySelectorAl but i know right now that its not so simple. So i wrote down that code and im stuck. I dont know what's wrong with that. Can somebody help me with it ? Cheers

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='tilt-el'></div>
    <div class='tilt-el'></div>
    <div class='tilt-el'></div>
</div>
```

```
var destroy = document.querySelectorAll(".tilt-el");
var i;
var w = window.innerWidth;
VanillaTilt.init(destroy);

function unTilt(){ 
    if( w  <= 800) {
        destroy.vanillaTilt.destroy();
    }
};

for(i=0;i<destroy.length;i++){
    destroy[i].addEventListener('mousemove', unTilt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll(".tilt-el");` is return array of element so your function should be like:

```
function myFunction(i){ 
  if( w  <= 800) {
    destroy[i].vanillaTilt.destroy();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but no luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

So i rebuild my code and maybe somebody will use it or make it better but...
Too divs you cant put data-tilt etc. Why? I don't know but when im using it as a part of html it's not working.

Html should looks like :

```
<div class='tilt-el'></div>
<div class='tilt-el'></div>
<div class='tilt-el'></div>
```

Not like mine previous one :

```
<div class='tilt-el' data-tilt></div>
<div class='tilt-el' data-tilt></div>
<div class='tilt-el' data-tilt></div>
```

and JS

```
const w = window.innerWidth;
if(w > 600) { 
  VanillaTilt.init(document.querySelectorAll(".tilt"), {
  max: 30,
  speed: 3000
})}
else {
    console.log(w);
 }
```

Of course VanilltaTilt supports Nodelist so you dont have to do all loops etc.

I think it will works fine for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming vanillaTilt is already instantiated and must be destroyed, you could use this code. It iterates through the divs and desroys them one by one.

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".tilt-el");
VanillaTilt.init(boxes);

document.querySelector('#w').innerText = window.innerWidth;

if (window.innerWidth <= 800) {
  boxes.forEach(box => {
    box.vanillaTilt.destroy();
  });
}
```

```css
.container .tilt-el {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 2em auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  background-color: rgba(200,0,0,0.25);
}

pre {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-tilt/1.7.0/vanilla-tilt.js"></script>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='tilt-el' data-tilt data-tilt-max="50">one</div>
    <div class='tilt-el' data-tilt data-tilt-max="60">two</div>
    <div class='tilt-el' data-tilt data-tilt-max="70">three</div>
  </div>
  
  <pre><code>window.innerWidth = <span id="w">?</span></code></pre>
```

However, if you don't want the library loaded for users with smaller screens, it would be more effecient to check screen size *before* deciding whether to instatiate vanillaTilt. This will save you from loading and then immediately destroying

```js
if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
    const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".tilt-el");
    VanillaTilt.init(boxes);
}
```